# While Verifying email and reseting password, only the first created/registered user is being valid

Tags: node.js, jwt, nodemailer, email-verification, reset-password

Scenario : When I create/register user1 ,the verification mail is sent to that email id and he(user1) is being verified successfully and I am able to change password for user1.
After creating user1 , I am creating/registering user2 ,where the verification email is sent to the account .After clicking the link , it's becomes INVALID
Overall , I am only able to create one user

Languages used : MERN stack

Backend => route.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const Doctor = require("../models/doctorModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const authMiddleware = require("../middlewares/authMiddleware");
const sendEmail = require("../utils/sendMail");
const Token = require("../models/tokenModel");
const Appointment = require("../models/appointmentModel");
const moment = require("moment");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (userExists) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User already exists", success: false });
    }
    const password = req.body.password;
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    req.body.password = hashedPassword;
    const newuser = new User(req.body);
    const result = await newuser.save();
    await sendEmail(result, "verifyemail");
    res
      .status(200)
      .send({ message: "User created successfully", success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: "Error creating user", success: false, error });
  }
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await User.findOne({ data: req.body.userId });
    console.log(result);
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User does not exist", success: false });
    }
    if (user.isVerified === false) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User not Verified", success: false });
    }
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "Password is incorrect", success: false });
    } else {
      const dataToBeSentToFrontend = {
        id: user._id,
        email: user.email,
        name: user.name,
      };
      const token = jwt.sign(dataToBeSentToFrontend, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      });

      res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "Login successful", success: true, data: token });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: "Error logging in", success: false, error });
  }
});

router.post("/get-user-info-by-id", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId });
    user.password = undefined;
    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ message: "User does not exist", success: false });
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({
        success: true,
        data: user,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ message: "Error getting user info", success: false, error });
  }
});

router.post("/send-password-reset-link", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    await sendEmail(result, "resetpassword");
    res.send({
      success: true,
      message: "Password reset link sent to your email successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

router.post("/resetpassword", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tokenData = await Token.findOne({ token: req.body.token });
    if (tokenData) {
      const password = req.body.password;
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      await User.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: tokenData.userid,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });
      await Token.findOneAndDelete({ token: req.body.token });
      res.send({ success: true, message: "Password reset successfull" });
    } else {
      res.send({ success: false, message: "Invalid token" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

router.post("/verifyemail", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tokenData = await Token.findOne({ token: req.body.token });
    if (tokenData) {
      await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: tokenData.userid, isVerified: true });

      await Token.findOneAndDelete({ token: req.body.token });
      res.send({ success: true, message: "Email Verified Successlly" });
    } else {
      res.send({ success: false, message: "Invalid token" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Backend => sendEmail.js :

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const Token = require("../models/tokenModel");

module.exports = async (user, mailType) => {
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 587,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: "sh***********th@gmail.com",
        pass: "e**************l",
      },
    });

    const encryptedToken = bcrypt
      .hashSync(user._id.toString(), 10)
      .replaceAll("/", "");
    const token = new Token({
      userid: user._id,
      token: encryptedToken,
    });
    await token.save();
    let mailOptions, emailContent;
    if (mailType === "verifyemail") {
      emailContent = `<div><h1>Please click on the below link to verify your email address</h1> <a href="http://localhost:3000/verifyemail/${encryptedToken}">${encryptedToken}</a>  </div>`;

      mailOptions = {
        from: "sh************th@gmail.com",
        to: user.email,
        subject: "Verify Email For MERN Auth",
        html: emailContent,
      };
    } else {
      emailContent = `<div><h1>Please click on the below link to reset your password</h1> <a href="http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/${encryptedToken}">${encryptedToken}</a>  </div>`;

      mailOptions = {
        from: "shanshangeeth@gmail.com",
        to: user.email,
        subject: "Reset Password",
        html: emailContent,
      };
    }

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
// auth: {
//     user: "shanshangeeth@gmail.com",
//     pass: "erwsvgtamrplzssl",
//   },
```

Backend => authMiddleware.js :

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers["authorization"].split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          message: "Auth failed",
          success: false,
        });
      } else {
        req.body.userId = decoded.id;

        next();
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: "Auth failed",
      success: false,
    });
  }
};
```

Backend => tokenmodel.js :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userid: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const tokenModel = mongoose.model("tokens", tokenSchema);

module.exports = tokenModel;
```

When  I create/register user1 , the verification mail is sent to that email id and he(user1) is being verified successfully and I am able to change password for user1.
After creating user1 , I am creating/registering user2 ,where the verification email is sent to the account .After clicking the link , it's becomes INVALID
Overall , I am only able to create one user who's being verified

Answer (score 0):

In the "verifyemail" route handler is you are trying to access the body of the req which is null, remember that when a user clicks on that URL in the email, a get request is send. The token will then exist in the req.params object, Not req.body.

Try the changes below.

```js
router.get("/verifyemail/:token", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tokenData = await Token.findOne({ token: req.params.token });
    if (tokenData) {
      await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: tokenData.userid, isVerified: true });

      await Token.findOneAndDelete({ token: req.params.token });
      res.send({ success: true, message: "Email Verified Successlly" });
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but not working .
I already did this  in front-end      
  <Route
          path="/verifyemail/:token"
          element={
            <PublicRoute>
              <VerifyEmail />
            </PublicRoute>
          }
        />

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet for the **<VerifyEmail />** component, **user model** and the  **./utils/sendMail**?

Comment: Link - VerifyEmail -https://github.com/Shangeeth7/doctor_appointment_booking/blob/main/client/src/pages/VerifyEmail.js
Link userModel - https://github.com/Shangeeth7/doctor_appointment_booking/blob/main/models/userModel.js 
Link /utlis/sendMail - https://github.com/Shangeeth7/doctor_appointment_booking/blob/main/utils/sendMail.js
I don't know to share code snippet as I am new to stackOverflow, So I have shared my github links
Its contains all of my code , If you don't mind could you take a look what I am missing,Thanks.
Sorry for delay of reply